# Why am I asked to sign into Windows Store when downloading apps, when I am already signed in with a work account

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

I am setting up my new company laptop, which is a Hybrid AD joined device.

I have signed into the Windows Store with my work account, but every time I go to try and download an app, I am asked to sign in. If I attempt to enter my work credentials, I am told no Microsoft account exists.

Why would I be asked to sign in when I am already signed in?

Comment: What edition of Windows are you running exactly?  If you are being told there isn't a Microsoft Account associated with your work account that probably is the case.

Comment: Is there a limitation on the *corporate* account preventing an *individual employee* from purchasing applications from Microsoft?

Comment: We are using Windows 10 pro. As I understood it, I should still be able to sign in with a work account (which I've done) and not need to specifically have a Microsoft account.
I assume such restrictions would be somewhere within Azure AD? I don't think so, but if you can point me in the right direction, I'll take a look.